# Check if a user is signed out in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rspec, devise

I'm trying to check if an administrator is signed out in an Rspec test. However the usual signed_in? method can't be seen from rspec and isn't part of the RSpec Devise Helpers.

Something like this is what i have in place

```
before (:each) do
        @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:administrator)
        sign_in @admin
      end


      it "should allow the admin to sign out" do
        sign_out @admin
        #@admin.should be_nil
        #@admin.signed_in?.should be_false
        administrator_signed_in?.should be_false
      end
```

Is there anothe way to check the session of the administrator and see if he's actually signed in or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's really what you need [How To: Test controllers with Rails 3 and 4 (and RSpec)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29)

Just check `current_user`. It should be `nil`

Add. Good practice is using syntax like this

```
-> { sign_out @admin }.should change { current_user }.from(@admin).to(nil)
```

Comment: indeed. I had just found         subject.current_administrator.should be_nil in some old ruby code. I had no idea of subject before that. Thank you.

Comment: In my case for your example, would it not be current_administrator as administrator is the model used and not user?

Comment: `current_user` is devise helper. it refers to the signed user in current session, because you cannot sign in twice at the same time

Comment: undefined local variable or method `current_user'...

current_administrator works though. Odd.

Comment: Also, appreciate the link, but I had already read it and your 'current_user' variable was what stuck out and helped me solve this.

Comment: This only tests the devise test helper methods sign_in and sign_out.  What if I want to test that something in the site actually signs in a user or signs out a user? The current_user var is not available if I create a user with a Factory and then using Capabara capabilities log the user in.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `expect(subject.current_user).to eq your_expectation` for RSpec 3 syntax.

Answer (score 11):

```
it "should have a current_user" do
  subject.current_user.should_not be_nil
end
```

Found at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29

Answer (score 8):

Not a new answer, really, but my rep isn't high enough to comment...:

- If you've already overridden `subject`, the controller is available as `controller` in controller specs, so:

  ```
  expect { ... }.to change { controller.current_user }.to nil
  ```
- To check for a specific user, say generated by FactoryGirl, we've had good success with:

  ```
  let(:user) do FactoryGirl.create(:client) ; end
  ...
  it 'signs them in' do
      expect { whatever }.to change { controller.current_user }.to user
  end

  it 'signs them out' do
      expect { whatever }.to change { controller.current_user }.to nil
  end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
it "signs user in and out" do
  user = User.create!(email: "user@example.org", password: "very-secret")
  sign_in user
  expect(controller.current_user).to eq(user)

  sign_out user
  expect(controller.current_user).to be_nil
end
```

You can refer this link [devise spec helper link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-sign-in-and-out-a-user-in-Request-type-specs-(specs-tagged-with-type:-:request))